# wordpress query_posts with foundation 6 Accordion not working correctly

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am trying to amalgamate the [Foundation 6 accordion](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html) with wordpress on a template page with a custom post type.

here is the code I am using:

```
     <?php
  query_posts( array( 

      'post_type' => 'customposttypename', 
      'taxonomyname' => 'taxonomyslug',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
  ) );


 if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>


    <ul class="accordion" data-accordion>



  <li class="accordion-item " data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title"><?php the_title();?></a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
     <?php the_content();?>
    </div>



        </li>

</ul>
              <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In order for the accordion to render you need this minimal markup:

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      I would start in the open state, due to using the `is-active` state class.
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Which I have used (please see above)

The query displays the posts with the title and content just like how i want it to and it is wrapped in the foundation Accordion, but once a tab is opened i am not able to click on it again to close. I am aware that one has to be open at any given time unless otherwise specified ( i would like one to remain open each time ) I have more than one post. I was also wondering how I would go about adding the is-active class to the first post generated. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sounds more like a JS issue to me. Try using static content (By removing the loop and just copying the same data for multiple tabs) and if that work you will know its loop issue else it is a JS issue. (Also check browser's console, you may find some errors there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is adding a new `<ul>` for every post. What you really want is a single `<ul>` wrapped around all of the posts.

Query_posts is also frowned on because it alters the main query. You could use get_posts instead, and add a variable $i to determine whether you're on the first post or not. If you are, add the `is-active` class.

Try:

`<?php
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'customposttypename',
    'taxonomyname' => 'taxonomyslug',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
if(count($myposts) > 0) {
    ?><ul class="accordion" data-accordion><?php
    for($i=0; $i<count($myposts); $i++) {
        setup_postdata($myposts[$i]);
        ?><li class="accordion-item<?php if($i==0) { echo ' is-active'; } ?>" data-accordion-item>
            <a href="#" class="accordion-title"><?php echo $myposts[$i]->post_name; ?></a>
            <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            <?php echo $myposts[$i]->post_content; ?>
            </div>
        </li><?php
    }
    ?></ul><?php
} ?>`

//added and _

Comment: thank you for the help, I currently have WP_Debug on after implementing your code i get [_italic_]Notice: Use of undefined constant posts - assumed 'posts' [_italic_] Also The titles are not displaying correctly and the content is not showing up period.

Comment: I have replace setup_postdata( posts); with setup_postdata($posts); the notice is gone but the titles and content for the posts are not displaying correctly still

Comment: Hmm, this worked on my install with custom post types - I assume you replaced `customposttypename` and `taxonomyslug`? You could try replacing `<?php the_title(); ?>` with `<?php echo $posts[$i]->post_name; ?>` and the `<?php the_content(); ?>` with `<?php echo $posts[$i]->post_content; ?>`.

Comment: hey @redsweater I did replace the customposttype name and taxonomies with mine. also when i replace <?php the_title(); ?> with <?php echo $posts[$i]->post_name; ?> i get Undefined offset: 1  &  Undefined offset: 2 where the titles should be

Comment: Ah, I haven't had enough caffeine yet this morning - code is updated above. `setup_postdata` and the two `echo` lines need to reference `$myposts` not `$posts`.

Comment: Hey @redsweater thank you so much, the post title was still not displaying until i added a _ between post_name like so: <?php echo $myposts[$i]->post_name; ?> Now it works, Thanks again soooooo much for your help i appreciate it.